# PHPUnit - Enabling Colour Output in OSX

Tags: php, macos, phpunit

I'm having a problem getting PHPUnit colour output to work in OSX Terminal. I have the following in my PHP unit configuration file:

```
<phpunit colors="true" bootstrap="bootstrap.php"> *OTHER CONFIG HERE* </phpunit>
```

I am running the following command:

```
phpunit -c tests/phpunit.xml
```

I have also tried running it using the terminal flag `--colors`, but no matter what I try, I can't seem to enable colour output in PHPUnit. Colours definitely work in other terminal applications I've tried so I don't think it is an issue of colours not being enabled in my terminal. Is there anything else I can try? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the same issue that is described in https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/1690?

Comment: Thanks for your response, yes this appears to be the problem. Running `phpunit -v` returns version 4.3.4, whereas running `./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -v` returns version 4.6.4. I made a bash alias for phpunit to use the vendor version and coloured output now works so I'll accept this answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `.bash_profile` file in your home directory and add this line:

```
CLICOLOR=1
```

This should enable the colors.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I just checked my bash_profile and I already have that. Must have added it when I was trying to figure out why colours weren't showing. When I use `ls` I have coloured syntax, but still not working in PHPUnit.

Comment: In the settings of Terminal.app, have you enabled "Display ANSI colors" in your currently active profile?

Comment: Yep, 'Display ANSI colors' is enabled.